# Is there a way to edit site content when locally debugging an Azure web role?

Tags: azure

Basically I am trying to speed up development, and it seems if I want to fix a javascript bug or update some CSS, I have to stop the deployment entirely, make my change, and deploy again to the local emulator, and finally navigate to where I was.

I cannot run this project outside of the emulator, as I am using the new co-located caching option.

I feel like I am missing something simple here.  I have noticed that I can start up the emulator (30 seconds or so), and then start a second debugging session on the web project directly (another 10 seconds), and it does seem able to talk to the emulator ok, at least so far.  This is better, but still, a pain.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about Visual Studio and ASP.NET, this should all just work. If you're changing static files like JavaScript or CSS, you should be able to just save and then see the result. If you're changing code, you need to rebuild the web role project (*not* the cloud service project), and the changes should show up when you refresh. Of course, for that to work you have to Ctrl+F5 (run without debugging)... otherwise you won't be able to make changes at all.

Comment: OK - this is just weird.  I just created a brand new cloud project with a stock ASP MVC 4 site and as you suggest it "just works!" I just switched the project to using VS2012, the latest Azure SDK, and co-located cache - anything pop in your head about this rather large migration that would prevent this from working?

Comment: This is what I see, the project that's working it maps directly to the ASP MVC sites directory, as expected.  However, my existing project is actually mapping to obj\Debug\ under the root MVC site.  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Correction, it is in obj\Debug under the Cloud project, not the MVC site.

Comment: I found it, in my Cloud Project file somehow I had <packagewebrole>true</packagewebrole> in there.  I removed it and things are working as expected.